# What C# features would be removed if backwards compatibility were not an issue?

Tags: c#

Backwards compatibility is a big concern for language designers, especially when the language is as popular as C#. Over time languages accumulate obsolete features. It's considered good practice to avoid these features, but they are kept in the langage for compatibility with old releases.

**Which language features or base class libraries in C# should be removed if backwards compatibility were not an issue?**

I am not asking about features that some developers like and others loathe. I am interested in features that are (pretty much) universally regarded as best-avoided (perhaps because there is now an outright better way of doing the same thing).

Comment: How about GOTO?  As in GOTO "subjective and argumentative"?

Comment: Is there any way I could refine the question that would satisfy those people who want it closed? I realise that what language features each developer likes is subjective, but I think there are some things that are almost universally regarded as bad.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of it is besides a "debate", vote to close subjective and argumentative.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with "debate" as long as it does not devolve into name calling and mud slinging.

Comment: @JRob: What's the point of the "debate" in this case? What does it matter what would be removed if <some mythical condition existed>? It's nothing but a reason for argument, not debate, about the validity or lack thereof of C# language features or framework library functionality. There's no value in that "debate" other than argument.

Comment: The problem with "debate" is that it can go on forever with no solution, especially since one of the premises ("if backwards compatibility were not an issue") is outright false.

Comment: The counterfactual premise is just a heuristic for identifying dead weight - a new .NET developer might benefit from reading this by learning (to pick two examples from below) that they the framework contains better alternatives to ArrayList and ReaderWriterLock.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: exactly (and I speak as a new .Net developer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**ArrayList**.

There is no point in using it anymore. List<> is way better.

Comment: This isn't a C# feature, it's a BCL class, but I agree.

Comment: Except for those rare occasions where you might actually want to store a list of different types of objects.

Comment: Are we talking about C# features, or types in the BCL? ArrayList is in the latter, but the question is about the former it seems.

Comment: Though I guess you could just as easily use List<object>, eh?

Comment: List<Object> won't work?

Comment: List<Object> does work for different types of objects.

Comment: How many use cases are there for using List<object> anyway?  Seems like a bad idea in a language which is statically typed.  Better to use interfaces or base classes.

Comment: Generics is a C# feature, but List is a BCL class.

Comment: Generics aren't a C# feature, they're a CLR feature that's supported in C#; otherwise, VB.NET and C# generics wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: @Reshure: I have to use this class for serializing lists of properties for my application, using the Visual Studio/.NET Framework's Settings feature.

Answer (score 13):

I have heard several of the C# designers mention that they regret making arrays [covariant](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

Comment: +1 As very well explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an obvious answer but any class, property or method marked with the `[Obsolete]` attribute would probably be the first to be removed.

Comment: unless of course its also marked [Reincarnate(true)]

Answer (score 2):

Non-sealed types by default.

Answer (score 2):

When implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll have to implement `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` as well `System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: In fact, it's not only for backward compatibility reasons. It needs to be there to support enumerating any `IEnumerable` regardless of its type.

Answer (score 1):

The `ReaderWriterLock` class is basically pointless now in favor of the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class, which Microsoft themselves say [is recommended for all new development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx).

Comment: Just a nitpick: like other examples, this has to do with the .Net library, not C# itself.

Comment: @Neil: Interestingly, I did indicate that in my initial answer, but it was then mysteriously edited out for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Named attribute constructor parameters.

Currently, you set the named parameters with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
```

This is from the time of C#1, but now there are object constructors:

```
new Foo(explicit, values) { Implicit = value }
```

Which would result in the following Attribute constructor:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method) { Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true }]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars` field. Using it results in a security risk, but there's nothing they can do about it for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score -2):

From the BCL's:

1. COM Interop
2. StringCollection (Generic List)
3. StringDictionary (Generic Dictionary)

Comment: I wouldn't call COM Interop something solely related to "backward compatibility". There's plenty of *new* native development out there.COM Interop is an important piece for this interop, even when you do not use COM at all.

Comment: I use StringCollection when serializing collections of strings for app settings using the Visual Studio/.NET Framework Settings feature.

Answer (score -18):

Generic lists (as mentioned by Reshure) including "var".  I'm a proponent of explicitly declaring variables.

Edit: I think people are equating "generic lists" with "generics".  If you prefer, "untyped collections" such as Hashtable or ArrayList.

Comment: var is type inference and is not directly related to generics. It is pretty much required for linq and helps reduce unnecessarily-verbose type declarations (although it is open to abuse). In any case, it wouldn't be removed from the language...

Comment: Generic lists??? Also it's not because YOU don't like a feature that it should be removed.

Comment: Yeesh.  I'm all for anything that makes my C# look less like HTML.

Comment: Generic lists lend towards sloppy code.  I've seen way to many projects end up in "debug hell" because someone declare a variable as "object".  As for "var", I'm a proponent of self-documenting code, and "var x = foo()" tells me nothing about what 'x' is.